# My question is about phrasal verbs

Tags: phrasal-verbs

His father had packed his rucksack, but he had forgotten to take off (the rucksack) / take out (an item from the rucksack) when he went for a run.

Here, do we use take off or take out?

Comment: Are you talking about taking something _out of_ the rucksack, or _taking off_ the rucksack?

Comment: I have amended your sentence to mean what I think you intend. But you need to respond to Kate Bunting's question before anybody can answer you.

Comment: @RonaldSole I think you've edited the answer into the question: "take off/ take out" are the options the learner was trying to choose between.

Comment: @IMSoP I plead guilty, with mitigating circumstances. Apologies!  (Have upvoted your answer in penance.)

Answer (score 1):

> His father had packed in his rucksack,but which he had forgotten to take off/ take out when he went for a run.

There are a few mistakes in this sentence, which make it a bit unclear what you were trying to say, but I will try to guess.

First, I assume you mean that he put something into his rucksack. In that case, you can't just say "he packed in", you have to say:

> His father had packed *something* in his rucksack...

Or name what was put in:

> His father had packed *a big book* in his rucksack...

---

Next, "but which" doesn't make sense here. If you want to refer to the item in the rucksack, you need to use *it*:

> ... but he had forgotten to ____ *it*

With a phrasal verb, the "it" goes between the words, so the options are:

> ... but he had forgotten to take it off ...

and

> ... but he had forgotten to take it out ...

Alternatively, you can use "which" without "but":

> ... which he had forgotten to take off ...

or

> ... which he had forgotten to take out ...

---

Both "take off" and "take out" mean "remove", but are used differently.

"Take off" generally means removing something from the *outside*. It's the opposite of "put on", e.g. "in the morning, I put on my socks; in the evening, I take off my socks".

"Take out" generally means removing something from the *inside*. It's the opposite of "put in", and is what you want here:

> His father had packed something in his rucksack, but he had forgotten to take it out when he went for a run.

or:

> His father had packed something in his rucksack, which he had forgotten to take out when he went for a run.